# Symfony2 UniqueConstraint and UniqueEntity (Integrity Violation)

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity, unique, unique-constraint

I've got a little problem with a Doctrine entity for a few days now. I've defined it with a UniqueConstraint on two fields with a UniqueEntity Validation on these two fields after that. But after validating of my form with a adding of an entity already in base, no way to obtain my error message in my form.

Just an error message from Symfony :

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '339057986-00012' for key 'SIRET'

Here is my entity declaration, all seems fine to me but maybe have I forgotten or misunderstood something?

```php
<?php

namespace Proetco\FrontBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Proetco\FrontBundle\Entity\Entreprise
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="entreprise", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="SIRET", columns={"SIREN", "NIC"})}) 
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Proetco\FrontBundle\Entity\EntrepriseRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"SIREN","NIC"}, message="Cette entreprise est déjà enregistrée")
 */
class Entreprise {

protected $Siret;

/**
 * @var integer $id
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string $SIREN
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="SIREN", type="string", length=9)
 */
private $SIREN;

/**
 * @var string $NIC
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="NIC", type="string", length=5)
 */
private $NIC;

/**
 * @var string $RS
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="RS", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
 */
private $RS;

/**
 * @var string $NCOM
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="NCOM", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
 */
private $NCOM;

/**
 * @var string $CPOS
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="CPOS", type="string", length=5, nullable=true)
 */
private $CPOS;

/**
 * @var string $LCOM
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="LCOM", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
 */
private $LCOM;

/**
 * @var string $INSEE
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="INSEE", type="string", length=5, nullable=true, nullable=true)
 */
private $INSEE;

/**
 * @var string $DEP
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="DEP", type="string", length=2)
 */
private $DEP;

/**
 * @var string $ARR
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ARR", type="string", length=1, nullable=true)
 */
private $ARR;

/**
 * @var string $CAN
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="CAN", type="string", length=2, nullable=true)
 */
private $CAN;

public function getSiret()
{
    return $this->Siret;
}

public function setSiret($Siret)
{
    $this->Siret = $Siret;
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set SIREN
 *
 * @param string $sIREN
 */
public function setSIREN($sIREN)
{
    $this->SIREN = $sIREN;
}

/**
 * Get SIREN
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getSIREN()
{
    return $this->SIREN;
}

/**
 * Set NIC
 *
 * @param string $nIC
 */
public function setNIC($nIC)
{
    $this->NIC = $nIC;
}

/**
 * Get NIC
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getNIC()
{
    return $this->NIC;
}

/**
 * Set RS
 *
 * @param string $rS
 */
public function setRS($rS)
{
    $this->RS = $rS;
}

/**
 * Get RS
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getRS()
{
    return $this->RS;
}

/**
 * Set NCOM
 *
 * @param string $nCOM
 */
public function setNCOM($nCOM)
{
    $this->NCOM = $nCOM;
}

/**
 * Get NCOM
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getNCOM()
{
    return $this->NCOM;
}

/**
 * Set CPOS
 *
 * @param string $cPOS
 */
public function setCPOS($cPOS)
{
    $this->CPOS = $cPOS;
}

/**
 * Get CPOS
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getCPOS()
{
    return $this->CPOS;
}

/**
 * Set LCOM
 *
 * @param string $lCOM
 */
public function setLCOM($lCOM)
{
    $this->LCOM = $lCOM;
}

/**
 * Get LCOM
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getLCOM()
{
    return $this->LCOM;
}

/**
 * Set INSEE
 *
 * @param string $iNSEE
 */
public function setINSEE($iNSEE)
{
    $this->INSEE = $iNSEE;
}

/**
 * Get INSEE
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getINSEE()
{
    return $this->INSEE;
}

/**
 * Set DEP
 *
 * @param string $dEP
 */
public function setDEP($dEP)
{
    if (!isset($this->DEP))
        $this->DEP = '02';
    $this->DEP = $dEP;
}

/**
 * Get DEP
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getDEP()
{
    if (!isset($this->DEP))
        $this->DEP = '02';
    return $this->DEP;
}

/**
 * Set ARR
 *
 * @param string $aRR
 */
public function setARR($aRR)
{
    $this->ARR = $aRR;
}

/**
 * Get ARR
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getARR()
{
    return $this->ARR;
}

/**
 * Set CAN
 *
 * @param string $cAN
 */
public function setCAN($cAN)
{
    $this->CAN = $cAN;
}

/**
 * Get CAN
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getCAN()
{
    return $this->CAN;
}

public function retrieveSiren($siret)
{
    return substr($siret, 0, 9);
}

public function retrieveNic($siret)
{
    return substr($siret, -5, 5);
}

//contraintes de validation
//TODO : valider les champs avec Regex

public function isSIREN()
{

}

public function isNIC()
{

}

}
```

Comment: Maybe i don't catch the question but, what you want to obtain? A validation error directly into the form?

Comment: Yes, with the message defined in my UniqueEntity validation rule.

Answer (score 7):

It's too late to reply here, but still replying so that it can help others who are stuck with the same problem.

### Two things

- [UniqueConstraint](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#uniqueconstraint) is not needed unless you want to generate schema change queries from your entity.
- [UniqueEntity](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html) is what you need.

---

### Short Answer

The entity definition in the question looks fine, I think there can be either of the below two issues.

- You have added `fields={"SIREN","NIC"}` which means that they will together unique, but you might be wanting them to be unique individually
- Or you might not be validating the entity, which I think is highly unlikely but I still wanted to be checked
  `https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html#using-the-validator-service`

### Detailed Explanation below

Notice that I got rid of `, uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="SIRET", columns={"SIREN", "NIC"})}` from `@ORM/Table` annotation (because UniqueConstraint is not needed unless you want to generate schema definition out of the entity)

```php
<?php

namespace Proetco\FrontBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Proetco\FrontBundle\Entity\Entreprise
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="entreprise") 
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Proetco\FrontBundle\Entity\EntrepriseRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"SIREN","NIC"}, message="Cette entreprise est déjà enregistrée")
 */
class Entreprise {
    /**
     * Body of entity
     */
}
```

---

Also `fields={"SIREN","NIC"}` this means that you want both these columns together to be unique
If you want each one of them to be inidividually unique then you'll need two `UniqueEntity`

Something like below

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="entreprise") 
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Proetco\FrontBundle\Entity\EntrepriseRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"SIREN"}, message="Cette entreprise est déjà enregistrée")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"NIC"}, message="Cette entreprise est déjà enregistrée")
 */
```

---

After you have the above setup you'll need validate entity and handle errors in your form

Comment: It is not clear to me why a Symfony-constraint is better than an ORM-constraint. What do you mean with *`"UniqueConstraint is not needed unless you want to generate schema definition out of the entity"`*; can you explain better please? – Specifying `uniqueConstraints` on the table will allow to have a consistent database; while with a Symfony constraint the validation of combination-uniqueness is up to the Symfony framework (and *could* be bypassed). Your solution works, but I'm not sure removing `UniqueConstraint` is the right approach cause it gives a less strict DB.

Answer (score -1):

Why not putting `unique=true`?
Like that :

```php
/**
 * @var string $SIREN
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="SIREN", type="string", length=9,unique=true)
 */
private $SIREN;

/**
 * @var string $NIC
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="NIC", type="string", length=5,unique=true)
 */
private $NIC;
```

Comment: Because that only makes each of the fields/columns unique, not their combination.

Answer (score -1):

And adding "unique=true" does not allow to catch the error properly. I have the same issue. If I find why, I'll come back to tell it. Maybe it will help someone...

**EDIT:** (now it's an answer).
I saw loooooot of posts, and I didn't find any good solution.
It seems to be a bug : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/symfony2/veb6Leph2_w

So I used the same solution : a try/catch. I just have to suppose that the only exception thrown by the database is a unique constraint violation...

```
// ...
try {
 $this->persistAndFlush($user);

 return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('publish'));
}
catch (\PDOException $e) {
 $error = $this->trans('user.username.notUnique',array(),'validators');
}
// ...
```

It's not satisfactory but it works. And I lost enough time with that for today.

**Answer to vegemite4me:** Sorry but I'm not familiar with Stackoverflow. I didn't find the "comment" button, and still now, the only one I can see is the one to answer you. But it does not work... Either I'm unlucky, or I'm a noob, or the form is very very poorly done. Probably the three ones

Comment: Please add this as a comment. It is useful information, but not an answer.